# get current app's localization and directionality in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I want to get the app's current localization and find out the app's directionality (RTL or LTR) in the flutter class.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the used `Directionality` from the context where you want it with:

```
Directionality.of(context)
```

The same thing for `Localizations`, you can retrieve it from the context like this:

```
 Localizations.of(context, MaterialLocalizations);
```

Comment: Thank you, but how we can recognize whole app localization (not only context localization)

Comment: look, the MaterialApp compose of multiple widgets, like Directionality, Navigator, Localizations, Theme....,  not all of theme are InheritedWidget, but they can be found with the context, so trying to get theme like what I did produce in the answer will search over the widget tree until it found the exact widget of that type, which will be in the MaterialApp.

Comment: unless you explicitly invoke those widgets in your widget tree manually to change values of theme, then trying to reach a specific value with the context will search until it will find that invoked widget in the tree